# Algorithm to find the smallest box containing a set of 3D objects

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, 3d, trigonometry

This is a problem that I meet on Unity3D, but it's actually a request for help for a general graphical algorithm.
I have a set of 3D objects/meshes that form a map. To generalize let's say that they are arrays of 6 numbers: position and size.

I need to create a box that contains all these objects. The box must have the minimum possible volume. To generalize, we can say that also the box will end to be an array of 9 numbers: position, size and rotation.

So at the end I'm talking about a function that takes a set of array[6] and returns an array[9].

The box can be obviously rotated in 3 directions as needed, so it's not just "take the smallest and the biggest x, y and z values".

Probably this question can some how easily resolved with a few trigonometrical functions, but i don't have any idea of how to do it! I only could create something that does that iteratively, but that's not what I want.

A particular case of this problem could be to find the minimum box containing a set of points. Probably this question is easier and some how can be extended to the main problem. Anyway... I can't solve neither this one! :)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This one might be a bit tough to write your own solution for. Consider reading the paper [Finding Minimal Enclosing Boxes](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/Papers/MinVolBox.pdf) by Joseph O'Rourke. The gist of it is summarized in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the 3d convex hull of all the vertex. Using the points of the convex hull you can form the faces of the convex hull. Then incline one by one all the faces parallel to x-axis. Then find the min x/y/z and max x/y/z along each face rotation.Calculate the volume using min x/y/z and max x/y/z. Find the index corresponding to the minimum volume. Rotate back this volume using the rotation you used for the corresponding face. This problem is similar to the 2d problem of minimum area rectangle. For minimum area rectangle the reference is https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points

Comment: yes, this is the usual "reasonably good and simple" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick easy way to get the bottom left rear corner of your new box, and the top right forward corner.

Either:

```
List<GameObjects> gameObjects; // <-- your game objects here
List<Bounds> objectsBounds = gameObjects.Select(item => item.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds);

Vector3 min = objectsBounds.Min(item => item.min);
Vector3 max = objectsBounds.Max(item => item.max);
```

Or:

```
List<GameObjects> gameObjects; // <-- your game objects here
List<Bounds> objectsBounds = gameObjects.Select(item => item.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds);

Vector3 min = Vector3.one * Single.MaxValue;
Vector3 max = Vector3.one * Single.MinValue;
foreach(Bounds bounds in objectsBounds)
    if(bounds.min < min) min = bounds.min;
foreach(Bounds bounds in objectsBounds)
    if(bounds.max > max) max = bounds.max;
```

Comment: Although this would provide a bounding box, it doesn't address the harder part of the question - orienting the minimum bounding box. (It may not be axis-aligned.)

Comment: Indeed, I will explore a bit more.

Comment: Honestly, that seems impossible, as all objects can have individual orientations, and checking against all possible orientations sounds like a mathematical and procedural nightmare

Comment: In reality there's no need for it to be a perfect box, so your solution could be used. Something similar has also been provided on unity3d's forum. But the problem was so intriguing that I decided to post it here to know if there was a "perfect" algorithm for this problem from a mathematical point of view :)

Comment: @Beppi's There is one that's been used for a pretty long time, set out in O'Rourke's paper that I mentioned. However, I'm not aware of any implementation done for C#/Unity3D. Try checking for them in other languages though if you plan on investigating further. Could be an interesting (albeit lengthy) endeavour to write your own for Unity. Good luck!

Comment: This is completely wrong  :)  (1) the question is about a MINIMAL ALIGNED bounding box, which is utterly different from an AABB.  (2) Note that in Unity, if you are finding the AABB, **the function to do so is built-in to Unity .. Encapsulate**